# Python pandas dataframe, check if column value matches other column value for every row

Tags: python, pandas

Imagine having the columns username and userid.

```
Username UserId
user1    1
user1    1
user2    2
user3    1    <- this is wrong for example
user1    1
```

User3 has the same userid as user1, which is not supposed to be possible. How can I check if any of these occurences exist?

Comment: are the ids in sequential order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First remove all duplicates by both columns:

```
df1  = df.drop_duplicates(['Username','UserId'])
print (df1)
  Username  UserId
0    user1       1
2    user2       2
3    user3       1
```

And then get all duplicates by `UserId` - but here still more logic for ditingush if wrong value is for `user1` or `user3`:

```
dups = df1[df1['UserId'].duplicated(keep=False)]
print (dups)
  Username  UserId
0    user1       1
3    user3       1
```

---

Sample data - added next `user4` for I hope better data:

```
print (df)
  Username  UserId
0    user1       1
1    user1       1
2    user2       2
3    user3       1
4    user4       1
5    user4       1
6    user1       1
```

One idea is get counts per groups by both columns by [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['count'] = df.groupby(['Username','UserId'])['UserId'].transform('size')
print (df)
  Username  UserId  count
0    user1       1      3
1    user1       1      3
2    user2       2      1
3    user3       1      1
4    user4       1      2
5    user4       1      2
6    user1       1      3
```

Then remove duplicates and sorting by [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df1  = df.drop_duplicates(['Username','UserId']).sort_values(['UserId','count'])
print (df1)
  Username  UserId  count
3    user3       1      1
4    user4       1      2
0    user1       1      3
2    user2       2      1
```

Get all dupes:

```
mask1 = df1['UserId'].duplicated(keep=False)
dups = df1[mask1]
print (dups)
  Username  UserId  count
3    user3       1      1
4    user4       1      2
0    user1       1      3
```

Remove dupe with maximal count by chain [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with `keep='last'`:

```
dups_without_max_count = df1[df1['UserId'].duplicated(keep='last') & mask1]
print (dups_without_max_count)
  Username  UserId  count
3    user3       1      1
4    user4       1      2
```